# Method 'POST' not supported 405

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, post

I have a `POST` method for upload a file. for uploading a file a pass a `Token` on my `header`

```
private RessourceMetadata doSave(Ressource ressource) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        String tempFilePath = writeDocumentToTempFile(ressource);
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = createMultipartFileParam(tempFilePath);
        RessourceMetadata ressourceMetadata = getRestTemplate().postForObject(
                getServiceUrl()
                        + "/uploadFileProperties?group={group}&projectId={projectId}&version={version}&env={env}",
                parts, RessourceMetadata.class, ressource.getGroup(), ressource.getId(), ressource.getVersion(),
                ressource.getEnv());
        return ressourceMetadata;
    }
```

....

```
private MultiValueMap<String, Object> createMultipartFileParam(String tempFilePath) {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    parts.add("file", new FileSystemResource(tempFilePath));
    parts.add("Authorization", "hrYIwyXoKGkY2juJfJb012Qx768RtUYA");
    return parts;
}
```

***Error:***

```
o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
 2017-Jun-15 09:50:31.852 ERROR [main] f.g.d.d.w.c.ServiceClient - Error while uploading file
 org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

What is wrong on my code ?

***POST Method:***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFileProperties", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Authorization token", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header") })
public @ResponseBody RessourceMetadata uploadProperties(
        @ApiParam(name = "file", value = "fichier properties à uploader", defaultValue = "", required = true) @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @ApiParam(name = "group", value = "groupe projet", defaultValue = "", required = true) @RequestParam("group") String group,
        @ApiParam(name = "projectId", value = "id projet (francevisas, diplomatie...)", defaultValue = "", required = true) @RequestParam("projectId") String projectId,
        @ApiParam(name = "version", value = "version du projet", defaultValue = "", required = true) @RequestParam("version") String version,
        @ApiParam(name = "env", value = "environnement (dev, prod, formation...)", defaultValue = "", required = true) @RequestParam("env") String env) {

    try {
        Ressource ressource = new Ressource(file.getBytes(), group, projectId, version, env,
                PropertiesFileUtils.getPropertiesFilename());
        getRessourceService().save(ressource);
        return ressource.getMetadata();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("Error while uploading.", e);
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while uploading.", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems pretty clear. The URL doesn't accept POSTs. What's your question?

Comment: @shmosel why i can't post  ?

Comment: I don't know the exception format of spring but like that I would guess seeing `o.s.w.s.PageNotFound` that you are redirected to the "page not found" page because of an incorrect URL, page that don't support `POST`

Comment: Please post the `@Controller` method. It must have `method = RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: @JackFlamp i have post the `POST` Method

Answer (score 0):

In your doSave() method you call getServiceUrl() method and add your path to it. getServiceUrl() must be returning some other domain. To check it, go into Debug mode in doSave() method and see if getService method gives you the correct value. Additionally, try your POST request with the domain which getServiceUrl gives you from Postman.